# Why do I get Hundreds of Salesforce.com Alert emails a day?

Tags: email-alert

For at least a month or so on some days I literally receive hundreds of `Salesforce Alerts` email that notify me of maintainace windows or removals of server slowdowns. I don't wan't nor need nor know how to unsubscribe from that emails.

**How can I stop that nightmare?**

[image]

Comment: The alerts that you're showing are generally controlled by the "Receive the salesforce.com administrator newsletter" preference at the bottom of the user detail page and fire once per instance. I'm an admin in quite a few orgs, so there are times I get quite a few of these, but not as many as you! Are you an admin user in literally dozens/hundreds of Salesforce instances? If not (or possibly even if so), you should file a case with Salesforce to get you off the list. In the meantime, as a workaround, I would set up a mail routing rule to put these somewhere other than my main inbox :)